# Is there a way to see the memory usage on chrome as it happens?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way in the "timeline" of chrome dev tools to see the memory usage as the app runs? I really wish I could see the timeline memory usage stream as I interact so that when I do a manual garbage collection I could see "my place in time".

Comment: I have the very same problem, and I'd swear it worked like this in the past (before version `32` or something). Not sure what's going on.